# Google maps api is not supported type parameter for search bar only in autocomplete textbox

Tags: javascript

// This is my script source:

```
  <script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?      v=3.exp&sensor=true&libraries=places" ></script>
```

// filling  the textbox in this way:-

```
  var input =document.getElementById('autocomplete');
      var options = {
              type: ['(bar)']
          };

      var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,options);
```

//  Search box stops the working.

```
Thank You in Advance.
```